# Vulkan vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR causing exceptions to be thrown in Windows.Graphics.dll

Tags: c, exception, sdk, vulkan

This problem seems to have arisen after I updated Vulkan SDK to the latest version (currently 1.2.162.1).  I had also updated my Nvidia driver to the latest stable release (461.40).  It can be observed by running the cube demo.

The following debug message is appearing multiple times:

onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\devices\monitordevice.cpp(102)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFDF8AFD235: (caller: 00007FFDF8AF1EBE) LogHr(1) tid(447c) 8007001F A device attached to the system is not functioning.

followed by:

onecoreuap\windows\core\dispbroker\lib\displaymanager.cpp(377)\DispBroker.dll!00007FFDF8B90B3F: (caller: 00007FFDF8B90F47) Exception(1) tid(447c) D0000022 Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE0015D759 in vkcube.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x000000585E56DA40.

Stepping through the code, this is happening when vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR is called.

Is this a driver bug, or a bug in the SDK, or has something changed in Vulkan 1.2 that I don't know about?

Here is the same problem posted on the Windows forums: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/error-spam-when-calling/e8f1f620-448c-47b2-ac51-992064799814

Comment: We are not a product support forum. Try to downgrade the versions, and report it to the party that is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know what's causing the issue. That was my question. Downgrading does not help.

Comment: If downgrading does not help, then the SDK and driver was not the problem, no?

Comment: That's initially what I thought, however the problem only arose after upgrading, and then remained no matter what I did. I was wondering if there was some new environmental setting or some change in the KHR extensions. Are you able to reproduce the error? As I said, it can be observed by building and running the cube demo.

Comment: No, works fine for me. Maybe check if you have some overlay installed. If they are crap, they usually crash. Try `vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties`; that should basically return all layers that are enabled (even those against your will). Then also try to open a dump (does not really matter of which app). If there are some dlls listed that are not from `C:\Windows\` path, then one of those are probably the culprit.